# Friction Behavior at corners

Tags: homework-and-exercises, friction, home-experiment, statics

[image: Problem Diagram]

**The question:**

> Find the range of value of $L/D$ such that the system remains in static equilibrium. And explain why such a range exists and not just a single value.

This is the question where I encountered a confusion. I know how friction acts on plane surfaces. But how do I analyze the friction in two places of the diagram marked in red. It's especially confusing to understand in which direction does the normal force act at a corner. Help anyone? It would be great if no one posted a complete solution to the problem (I would love to solve it myself), but instead if someone could provide an **approach** to solve such a case.

Comment: look for rotational  equilibrium

Comment: Great sketch BTW.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147996/discussion-on-question-by-apekshik-panigrahi-friction-behavior-at-corners); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Friction always acts perpendicular to the normal force, and parallel to relative motion (but in an opposite sense).

In this case, I have noted the normal force vectors in green and the friction vectors in magenta.

[image: fig1]

As you can see, when an odd shape or a corner is in contact with a straight edge, then the normal force *is always* perpendicular to that edge, regardless on which body the straight edge belongs to.

You can also slide the normal vectors along their line of action (contact normal line) until they meet

[image: fig2]

Where they meet is the center of rotation (shown as a blue arc arrow), and any force that goes through the center of rotation does zero work, which is the definition of a constraint force. Where they meet is also where the *combined* normal forces act though.

Also shown is gravity in cyan through the center of mass.

Also, slide the friction forces to where they meet to find where the *combined* friction forces act through.

[image: fig3]

Finally, the combined normal force (green) and combined friction force (magenta) must meet at a single point, along the line of action of gravity (cyan line) in order to counter-act it for static equilibrium.

Above I describe the geometry of statics, which is a beautiful subject, not taught in school. It helps in the visualization of forces and understanding why they point at the direction they do.

Answer (score -1):

Let the lower contact point be A and the upper point be B.  Also let the CG of the rod be at its centre and the rod has only the length dimension, no breath and width.

Then let the reaction at A be $R_A$ normal to the wall (point to the right), so the friction is pointing up $\mu R_A$ since the rod tends to fall down.

At point B the reaction $R_B$ is normal to the rod and the friction $\mu R_B$ is along the rod towards the right since the rod tends to move towards to the left.

Consider the horizontal forces we have
$$R_A + \mu R_Bcos\theta = R_Bsin\theta$$

Vertically we have

$$\mu R_A + R_Bcos\theta + \mu R_Bsin\theta = mg$$

Solving for $R_B$ we have

$$R_B = \frac{mg}{2\mu sin\theta + (1 - \mu ^2)cos\theta}$$

Taking moment at A we have
$$R_B\frac{d}{cos\theta} = mg \frac{L}{2}cos\theta$$

$$\implies \frac{L}{d} = \frac{2}{cos^2\theta[2\mu sin\theta + (1 - \mu ^2)cos\theta]}$$

Hence $\frac{L}{d}$ depends on $\mu$ and $\theta$.  Also $\theta$ cannot be 90 degrees.

Answer (score -1):

The formal approach to statics *always* follows these specific steps

1. **Kinematics**. Even though this is a statics problem, it has the potential to move, and even if it did not (like a bridge), you still need to identify the position of each important point, labeled **A**, **B**, and **C** above with respect to the coordinate origin **0**. Include the coordinate system used to measure positions and sum torques about.

   **Draw a kinematic diagram** that includes all important points (with labels), all angles defined in a positive sense (unless otherwise specified). In the diagram below I have included the projected points **A'** and **B'** onto the axis of the body since they are used to solve for the coordinates of **A**, **B** and **C**.

   [image: fig1]

   Find the position of **A** by relating the position of **B** which is known as $(d,0)$ through the body

   $$\begin{array}{r|l}
   \text{x-axis} & d = r + (\ell-r-s)\cos \theta + r \sin \theta \\
   \text{y-axis} & 0 = y_A + (\ell-r-s) \sin \theta - r \cos \theta \\
   \end{array}$$

   Notice that the coordinate $y_A$ is included in the equation as if it was a positive value (per our coordinate convention) even though the solution will result in a negative value indicating to us that indeed point **A** is *below* the horizontal *x*-axis.

   Anyway, the above is solved for $y_A$ and $s$ and will provide us with the solution for the position of the kinematic hardpoints

   $$\begin{array}{r|l}
   \text{point A} & (0,\,y_A) \\
   \text{point B} & (d,\,0) \\
   \text{point C} & (x_C,\,y_C) = \left(r + (\ell/2-r) \cos \theta,\,y_A+(\ell/2-r) \sin \theta \right)
   \end{array}$$

   I think there is a simplification of $r \rightarrow 0$ for the question asked, but I am not sure.
2. **Draw a Free Body Diagram (FBD)** that includes all forces and torques (with labels) acting on the body.

   [image: fig2]

   This is used to write down the 3 force/torque balance equations. Here assume that the friction forces $F_A$ and $F_B$ can take *any* value without restriction (infinite coefficient of friction). Later when we have the results we can examine cases where friction is limited by a traction limit.

   $$\begin{array}{r|l}
   \text{Forces along x-axis} & N_A - N_B \sin \theta + F_B \cos \theta = 0\\
   \text{Fprces along y-axis} & F_A - m g + N_B \cos \theta + F_B \sin \theta = 0 \\
   \text{Torques about 0} & -y_A N_A - x_C m g + d (N_B \cos \theta + F_B \sin \theta )  = 0
   \end{array}$$

   The above 3 equations can be solved for three unknowns, but we have 4 unknowns at this point. These are the two normal forces $N_A$ and $N_B$ as well as the two friction forces $F_A$ and $F_B$.
3. **Solution Special Cases** for finite friction $\mu$.

   - Point **A** is just about to slip, with $F_A = \mu N_A$. The solution of the system of equations above will yield $N_A$, $N_B$ and $F_B$ and you can explore the limits when $F_B/N_B < \mu$ for all possible values of $\ell/d$.
   - Point **B** is just about to slip, with $F_B = \mu N_B$. The solution of the system of equations above will yield $N_A$, $N_B$ and $F_A$ and you can explore the limits when $F_A/N_A < \mu$ for all possible values of $\ell/d$.